# Image file not saving

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I am kind of new to Webmatrix and attempting to create a profile page with a photo that can be updated. I can't seem to work out why its not working but my code looks fine to me. Can somebody please look through the code below and let mew know what I'm doing wrong?

**Disclaimer** - I am a hack developer trying to teach myself so please excuse the bad syntax and anything else you see.

```
@{
if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login?returnUrl="
        + Request.Url.LocalPath);
}    

Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Update Profile";


WebImage photo = null;
var newFileName = "";
var imagePath = "";

var UserID = "";
var Email = "";
var FirstName = "";
var LastName = "";
var DOB = "";
var EmploymentStatus = "";
var CurrentTitle = "";
var Company = "";
var LinkedInURL = "";
var Resume = "";
var Photo = "";
var ContractorIntro = "";

if(!IsPost){
    if(!Request.QueryString["UserID"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["UserID"].IsInt()) {
        UserID = Request.QueryString["UserID"];
        var db = Database.Open("JobsLoop");
        var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile WHERE UserID = @0";
        var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, UserID, DOB);

            if(row != null) {
            UserID = row.UserID.ToString();
            FirstName = row.FirstName;
            LastName = row.LastName;
            EmploymentStatus = row.EmploymentStatus;
            CurrentTitle = row.CurrentTitle;
            Company = row.Company;
            DOB = row.DOB.ToString(format: "dd/MM/yy");
            LinkedInURL = row.LinkedInURL;
            Resume = row.Resume;
            Photo = row.Photo;
            ContractorIntro = row.ContractorIntro;



        }
    }
    else{
        Validation.AddFormError("No Profile was selected.");
        // Use the following line instead for versions of ASP.NET Web Pages 2 earlier
        // than the RC release.
        //ModelState.AddFormError("No movie was selected.");
    }
}




if(IsPost){
    Validation.RequireField("UserID", "You must enter a user ID");
    Validation.RequireField("FirstName", "First Name is required");
    Validation.RequireField("LastName", "No Last Name was submitted!");
    Validation.RequireField("DOB", "No DOB was submitted!");
    Validation.RequireField("EmploymentStatus", "No Employment Status was submitted!");
    Validation.RequireField("CurrentTitle", "No Current Title was submitted!");
    //Validation.RequireField("LinkedInURL", "No LinkedIn address was submitted!");


    UserID = Request.Form["UserID"];
    FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
    LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
    DOB = Request.Form["DOB"];
    EmploymentStatus = Request.Form["EmploymentStatus"];
    CurrentTitle = Request.Form["CurrentTitle"];
    Company = Request.Form["Company"];
    LinkedInURL = Request.Form["LinkedInURL"];
    Resume = Request.Form["Resume"];
    Photo = Request.Form["Photo"];
    ContractorIntro = Request.Unvalidated["ContractorIntro"];


    if(Validation.IsValid()){

    photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
    if(photo != null)
    {
        newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +
            Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
        imagePath = @"profile\" + newFileName;
        photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
        Photo = @newFileName;

    }
    else 
    {

    }


     if(newFileName.IsEmpty())
    {
        var db = Database.Open("JobsLoop");
        var updateCommand = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName=@1, LastName=@2, DOB=@3, EmploymentStatus=@4, CurrentTitle=@5, Company=@6, LinkedInURL=@7, Resume=@8, ContractorIntro=@9  WHERE UserID=@0";
        db.Execute(updateCommand, UserID, FirstName, LastName, DOB, EmploymentStatus, CurrentTitle, Company, LinkedInURL, Resume, ContractorIntro);
    }
    else{
    if(Validation.IsValid()){
        var db = Database.Open("JobsLoop");
        var updateCommand = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName=@1, LastName=@2, DOB=@3, EmploymentStatus=@4, CurrentTitle=@5, Company=@6, LinkedInURL=@7, Resume=@8, ContractorIntro=@9, Photo=@10   WHERE UserID=@0";
        db.Execute(updateCommand, UserID, FirstName, LastName, DOB, EmploymentStatus, CurrentTitle, Company, LinkedInURL, Resume, ContractorIntro, Photo);
      }
      }
   }

}

 }
```

Comment: Is the form's action set to POST and the enctype set to "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: This is what I have used: <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

Comment: I fixed the problem, I had an extra <form> section in the html that was causing the problem